# Change my Apple ID email address on iCloud account

Tags: apple-id, icloud

I had to make a new email address for my new Apple ID since I forgot my previous Apple ID password and couldn't receive a verification email.

Now that I have my new Apple ID and password, my iPhone 4s still shows my old Apple ID. How can I change it so that my new Apple ID shows when I wish to download anything?

My iCloud account still has my old Apple ID and is in grey; so I can't change it! I don't want to delete my old iCloud account.

Answer (score 7):

Go to https://appleid.apple.com, click Manage my Apple ID and sign in with your current iCloud ID.

Tap edit next to the primary email account, tap Edit, change it back to your old email address and save the change.

Then edit the name of the account to change it back to your old email address.  You can now use your current password to turn off Find My iPhone on your device, even though it prompts you for the password for your old account ID.

Then go to Settings > iCloud, tap Delete Account and choose Delete from My iDevice when prompted (your iCloud data will still be in iCloud).

Next, go back to https://appleid.apple.com and change your primary email address and iCloud ID name back to the way it was.  Now you can go to Settings > iCloud and sign in with your current iCloud ID and password.

Comment: I would like to change it to my new email address.

Comment: I don't know my old password for my old email which is my current I cloud email.

Comment: How can I make my new apple ID show in my iCloud account if I don't remember my old iCloud pass word?

Comment: When I wish to down load off apple account my old email is prompted instead of my new email.. Which I know the pass word for.

Comment: Maybe you can contact to Apple support for some help. like reset your password..

Comment: The above answer by robin0823 is brilliant! I was having such a headache with this and that solution worked like a charm!