# I would like to change my iCloud email

Tags: icloud, apple-id

So I have changed my iTunes email to my current email address but it still says that I have my old email is attached to my iCloud.

So now under in my settings, under I cloud, I have my name then underneath it says

> iCloud: ( old email).
>   Store: (my new email).

- I would like to change it to my new email address, but I can not access my old iCloud account or the old email as I have forgotten the passwords.
- I don’t care if I don’t have any of my information on iCloud later I never use it anyway.

How can I change this or turn iCloud off all together without a password to anything other then my new account?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change my Apple ID email address on iCloud account](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106290/change-my-apple-id-email-address-on-icloud-account)

Comment: Tia - can you upload an image of the settings you are using? We can’t guess if you’re in a web browser, on an iPhone, on a Mac, on a PC. We could say - ask apple help, but if you edit this to add details, we might be able to really help you well with step by step details

Answer (score 1):

If I understand things, you wish to walk away from the “old email” entirely - lose all cloud data, lose all purchases and make a new iCloud / AppleID on your new email.

If so, you’re going to need a few things and some luck or a call to Apple Support. Here are some limitations.

1. If your device is activation locked, you can’t walk away from the old iCloud - you have to recover that account. You will need to prove to Apple using a rigorous process (they will not deviate from the script, some steps will take days) if you can’t provide the security questions, receive a secondary email or remember and enter the password.
2. If your new email is associated in any way with the old AppleID / old iCloud you can’t use it for a new account or even associate it with a new account.

Assuming all of the above are OK, you would sign out of every iCloud using the old - all mac, PC, iPad, iPhone, iPod, Apple TV. Then you would set up your new AppleID - have it use your new email and then proceed to sign in on each device.