# iCoud has divorced name - help

Tags: icloud, apple-id

I got a divorce, and my iCloud email has my old name. I did an alias, but I want that old name gone. Now what?

Comment: My hunch is the alias was your attempt to change everything which we can’t do without Apple’s explicit help. Let me know in comments if I didn’t guess what you wanted changed from the brief description.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change my Apple ID email address on iCloud account](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106290/change-my-apple-id-email-address-on-icloud-account)

Answer (score 1):

There are two options. The important part is to determine if you need to get a new @icloud or @me or @mac portion of the email. You can’t change that yourself.

You can change the AppleID (log in text) and everything else like name and address, just not the initial email Apple issued to your iCloud account. That portion isn’t editable any manner I’ve ever seen, and if you use a third party mail with your AppleID you can change that to a new value and leave the old email behind forever.

Assuming you can’t edit the fields you want, two options remain:

1. Make a new AppleID and have the other hang around for past purchases - you have to keep control of it, but not use it for primary. Make it part of the “family” if you want purchases to flow to the new account.
2. Make a new AppleID and just delete / leave it unused. Clean start.

I would call Apple Support or chat if any of this is unclear or confusing. Show them the exact parts you want to change before you do anything. They can advise you best since they manage the service and you don’t have to share personal details here publicly.

Comment: I rock too. Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can change or delete an email alias, and you can sign in to iCloud with either your @icloud.com email address or the Apple ID that you use with your iCloud account (this can be changed to any email address of yours, e.g. Gmail).

@icloud.com email address that is not an alias cannot be deleted. But you could just not use it. If you change your Apple ID and create a new @icloud.com email alias, your divorced name account will only be shown to you in your settings, it won’t be publicly visible unless you show it, and you don’t have to use it.

I’m in a similar situation myself due to last name change. I had my old email listed in my System Preferences but it doesn’t appear anywhere else because I use my Gmail as my Apple ID.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202667
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201771

Comment: Woo! For people that brought their email (not the default situation for AppleID / iCloud - Apple steers people to establish a new account in most new device setup assistants) this is much easier.

Comment: @bmike nothing wrong with own email address, it’s essentially just your username. There is absolutely zero difference if you use your iCloud account or your Gmail/Hotmail/whatevermail to authenticate. I would not advice establishing a new account. My account has my whole history with Apple from my first device, all support requests, all devices registered to it, Discussions forum account, iTunes account, etc. This comes in useful.

Comment: I think you misunderstand my comment. I’m not advocating anyone make a new account, do anything but that. My comment was the majority of AppleID created on device as part of an enrollment don’t use third party emails. The implication is most people might not be in the case of you and Amy.